# Transverse and longitudinal photon propagator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, propagator, ward-identity

I'm studying QED renormalization and the Ward-Takahashi identity, and I'm having trouble understanding two things about the longitudinal and transverse parts of the photon propagator.

**What I understand:** when one wants to study the *exact* photon propagator $G_ {\mu\nu}=\langle A_\mu A_\nu\rangle$ and one knows the *free* propagator in Feynman gauge $D_ {\mu\nu}=-i\frac{\eta_ {\mu\nu}}{k^2+i\epsilon}$ with $G_ {\mu\nu}=D_ {\mu\nu} +\text{(loop)} $, one uses the WTI with $G_ {\mu\nu}$ (as it works for every order of perturbation) and obtains $$k^\mu G_ {\mu\nu}(k)=-i\frac{k_\nu}{k^2}$$
One then writes $G_ {\mu\nu}=G_ {\mu\nu}^{(T)}+G_ {\mu\nu}^{(L)}$, where $G_ {\mu\nu}^{(T)}$ is the transverse component and $G_ {\mu\nu}^{(L)}$ is the longitudinal one, and shows that the above relation works also for $D_ {\mu\nu}$.

**What I don't understand:** how can I know the expressions of $G_ {\mu\nu}^{(T)}$ and $G_ {\mu\nu}^{(L)}$? How can I show, from the fact that $D_ {\mu\nu}$ satisfies the WTI, that particularly $G_ {\mu\nu}^{(L)}$ doesn't have loop corrections?

Comment: what is $G^L$ and $G^T$? Is $G^T=D$, $G^L=\text{loop}$?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform no, they are the longitudinal and transverse components. Sorry, I'll edit the question to clarify it.

Comment: By longitudinal you mean $G^L_{\mu\nu}\propto k_\mu k_\nu$? By transverse you mean $k^\mu G^T_{\mu\nu}=k^\nu G^T_{\mu\nu}=0$?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I guess so, but I'm not sure: they are terms I found on books and lectures as a "decomposition of the propagator" so that $G_ {\mu\nu}=G_ {\mu\nu}^{(T)}+G_ {\mu\nu}^{(L)}$ and $G_ {\mu\nu}^{(L)}$ doesn't have quantum corrections.